# Is there a way to increase the cyclomatic capacity of an input variable

Tags: python, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm working on making a tic tac toe game and I have more complex code than my input statement can handle.

This is for a project in my class and I've done some research. nothing to me makes sense there so I came here. I tried to make it less complex but nothing can get around my head to do so. The bellow code is just a small portion of the results.

```
while while_statement == 3:
  X_variables = input('where do you place your X player1. {use (X , Y)}. ')
  if X_variables == '(1 , 1)':
    game = [[1 , 0 , 0],
      [0 , 0 , 0],
      [0 , 0 , 0]]
    print('|' , 'X' , '|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|')
    print('-------------')
    print('|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|')
    print('-------------')
    print('|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|')
  elif X_variables == '(1 , 2)':
    game = [[0 , 0 , 0],
      [1 , 0 , 0],
      [0 , 0 , 0]]
    print('|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|')
    print('-------------')
    print('|' , 'X' , '|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|')
    print('-------------')
    print('|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|' , ' ' , '|')
```

I expect this code will continue with the game but the actual results will be an error in the X_variables input statement.

Comment: cyclomatic complexity is not associated with input variable

Comment: I get it from the input variable. that's what the problem is. it comes from there nothing else, and so if I could increase it, I could continue on with the rest of the results.

Comment: If you want to clean up the code . Create a class for representing the state of the game (the game variable here ) and define `__str__`  on that class which returns a string representing printable game view

Comment: cyclomatic complexity :  It is a quantitative measure of the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source code.

Can you explain what exactly do you want to increase here?

Comment: check the answer

Comment: im trying to increase the threshold of it.

Comment: What do you mean  by threshold here ?

Comment: as much as the complexity can hold. the error exactly is: "[mccabe] Cyclomatic complexity too high: 20 (threshold 15)".

Comment: that is not in this part mostly, try my answer below it would bring down the complexity. It would make sure complexity is not associated to input range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be cleaned up to following for flexibility in terms of input. 
The code assumes input to be valid, you may want to handle exceptions later

```
class Board:
  def __init__(self,count):
    self.count = count
    self.game = [[0 for _ in range(count)] for _ in range(count)]

  def __repr__(self):
    line = "\n"+"- "*self.count+"\n"
    return line.join(["|".join([ 'X' if y == 1 else ' ' for y in x ]) for x in self.game])

  def place(self,x,y):
    self.game[x][y] = 1


.
.
.
board = Board(5)
.
.
.
while while_statement == 3:
  row,col = map(int,tuple(input("Input here:(format row,col)").split(',')))
  board.place(row,col)
  print(board)
```

Comment: what exactly is happening. I don't see what is I tried it. II'm a bit confused on what class board is also.

Comment: You can not copy paste it as such. Board represents a game , last 4 lines does what your while loop does

Board is the tic-tac-toe board. The point is you don't need to have if statement for every index

Comment: you can create an instance of Board , say `board = Board(5)` and try `board.place(1,2)` etc and try printing the board

Comment: ok, thank you. How do I say this was answered?? I'm slightly new to this sight.

Comment: you can accept my answer as the right answer by clicking the tick mark near the answer on left.  Thanks